# How do I determine the capacity of my generator when it has a separate starting watts capacity?

Tags: electrical, generator

I have a Briggs & Stratton Storm Responder generator that is rated at 5500 watts with a 8250 startup watts capacity.  The user manual is a little confusing: it seems to state that I have to take the starting wattage of each appliance into account when I compute the wattage load so I don't exceed the maximum running capacity (5500 watts, in my case).  So what do I do with the "8250"?  How does that factor into the equation?

Answer (score 1):

If you take the running watts that should be enough. The starting watts should be taken into account by the 8250 number. This is assuming every connected load will not be starting at the exact same time.

Answer (score 0):

motors have a surge load upon starting which is higher than running load requirements.  Use the rated amps of desired appliances or tools,that will be fine when matched with running wattage of the generator.
remember Watts = Amps x Volts
5500/110 =  50 amps
A couple of caveats though:
older motors may not be as efficient as factory specs. 
Longer wire runs reduce amp rating as does undersized wire.
Also, hot wires have reduced carrying capacity
Cold motors have higher surge than warmed up motors. 
Example: A 15 amp old air compressor may trip a 20 amp breaker.
hopes this helps

Comment: Why are you using 110 volts in your calculation?